# Made a mistake weight painting now i cant reset weight values of bones to the automatic ones

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting, vertex-weights

Im new in blender and i was tryign to rig arms for my 3d project but they would deform a lot. I tried a lot of things, one of them changing weight painting from the automatic one. But now i realized i made a mistake there and i want to reset the values to the original ones.
I searched in this page for a solution, i tried selecting the bones, typing spacebar, search weight from bones -> automatic but blender would lag and after that say that that it was not possible to do that.
i ve been a lot of days stressed trying to find a solution i would appreciate if someone could answer[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the vertex groups from the object then try automatic weight.
You can select a vertex group and press the "-" button or press the "special button" (marked red) and select "delete all groups".

## [image]

Comment: Please explain how to remove vertex groups from a mesh ideally with an illustration of the procedure